# Randomize what picturebox the image will go into

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to visual basics and was wondering how to put an image into a randomized picture box. I have 4 picture boxes and one image. When you click the button "Jouer" I want the image to appear in the picture box that the computer has chosen. Thanks in advance. This is the code I've tried so far:

```
   Private Sub btnJouer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJouer.Click
    T(0) = PictureBox1
    T(1) = PictureBox2
    T(2) = PictureBox3
    T(3) = PictureBox4

    lbl1.Text = lbl1.Text - 1

    Dim rand As New Random()
    For i = 0 To 3
        Randomize()
        Image = My.Resources.mario1
        Trouver = Image.ToString
        Trouver = rand.Next(0, T.Count)
    Next

  End Sub
```

Comment: You need to have Option Strict On for this project and all you projects. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also in the Tools menu Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.

Answer (score 1):

With some hard-coding of four PictureBoxes, it can be done simply with a Case statement

```vb
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim image = My.Resources.mario1
Dim i = rand.Next(4) ' 0, 1, 2, 3
Select Case i
    Case 0
        PictureBox1.Image = image
    Case 1
        PictureBox2.Image = image
    Case 2
        PictureBox3.Image = image
    Case 3
        PictureBox4.Image = image
End Select
```

Randomize is meant to be used with the old-style vb.net Rnd function, and the Random class doesn't require it.

Without hard-coding four PictureBoxes, you can specify the number of PictureBoxes and the prefix in the name

```vb
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim image = My.Resources.mario1
Dim i = rand.Next(4) ' 0, 1, 2, 3

Dim numberOfPictureBoxes = 4
Dim pictureBoxPrefix = "PictureBox"

Dim myPictureBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find($"{pictureBoxPrefix}{i + 1}", True).Single(), PictureBox)
myPictureBox.Image = image
```

Of course, you may want to clear all the PictureBoxes before setting one, so they are all cleared. You can use Me.Controls, but the PictureBoxes must be in the form, not in a different control such as a Panel or GroupBox. If that's the case use that container instead: `container.Controls.Cast(Of Control...`

```vb
Dim myPictureBoxes = Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control).Where(Function(c) c.Name.Contains(pictureBoxPrefix)).Cast(Of PictureBox)()

For Each pb In myPictureBoxes
    pb.Image = Nothing
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to declare `Random` as a class level variable. You then reuse the same instance each time you click the button. If you use a local variable and click the button quickly `Random` may use the same seed which is based on the system clock.

I also made the array of picture boxes a class level variable so I didn't have to rebuild it each time the button is clicked. I initialized the array in the `Form.Load` so we have already created `PictureBox`es to fill it.

When you turn on `Option Strict`, you will see it is unwise to try to do arithmetic with `String`s. Also assigning an `Integer` to a `Text` property (`Text` properties are `String`) is not correct.

I cleared all the picture boxes then got the index from the `Random` instance. I see you realize that the `Next` method parameters are inclusive of the first parameter and exclusive of the second parameter.

Assuming that the image has been assigned to the `Resources` correctly, we just need to assign it to the randomly selected `PictureBox` in the array.

```
Private Rand As New Random()
Private PBs() As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PBs = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3}
End Sub

Private Sub btnJouer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label1.Text = (CInt(Label1.Text) - 1).ToString
    For Each pb In PBs
        pb.Image = Nothing
    Next
    Dim index = Rand.Next(0, PBs.Count)
    PBs(index).Image = My.Resources.compiles_ship_it
End Sub
```

I changed a few control names and the name of resource to match my test program. I think you will be able to follow it anyway.